# but more the technical

Tags: comprehension

Source: [UNIX System Administration—A Beginner's Guide by Steve Maxwell (2002)](https://books.google.com/books/about/UNIX_System_Administration_A_Beginner_s.html?id=tIAhAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)

Example:

> Certainly this is the ideal situation, but the world is full of situations that are far from perfection. As a result, many successful administrators don't need to deal with the softer side, **but more the technical**.

Check my comprehension please:
As a result, many successful administrators don't need to deal with the softer side, but instead they need to deal more with the technical side.

Comment: Yes, I'd agree with your interpretation.

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct.  With a parallel structure like 'softer side... technical side', we sometimes omit the second instance of the noun (side, in this case).

Comment: For the sake or parallellism, the author might have written "less with the softer side and more with the technical" instead of "don't need to deal...but more..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.

**@Tᴚoɯɐuo** makes a very good comment:

> For the sake or parallellism, the author might have written "less with the softer side and more with the technical" instead of "don't need to deal...but more..." –